# Remote connection with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have gone through the the official documentation to install mongodb in linux environment in amazon.

after installation i did

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-51 etc]# service mongod restart
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
Stopping mongod:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]
```

the start is failed but when i write only mongod is says

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-51 etc]# mongod
2016-09-21T05:23:57.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16633 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ip-172-31-20-59
2016-09-21T05:23:57.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-09-21T05:23:57.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-09-21T05:23:57.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
2016-09-21T05:23:57.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-09-21T05:23:57.703+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-09-21T05:23:57.704+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-09-21T05:23:57.704+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: amazon
2016-09-21T05:23:57.704+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-09-21T05:23:57.704+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-09-21T05:23:57.704+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-09-21T05:23:57.726+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2016-09-21T05:23:57.735+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2016-09-21T05:23:57.735+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2016-09-21T05:23:57.899+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2016-09-21T05:23:57.899+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-21T05:23:57.907+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-09-21T05:23:57.907+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-09-21T05:23:57.907+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
```

and then on another console i started `mongo`

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-59 etc]# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-09-21T05:23:57.905+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
```

and in mongod console it accepted the connnection

```
2016-09-21T05:25:09.684+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49068 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

Now i have a couple of questions,

1.i am not able to understand is my mongo is working or not? (beacause starting mongod always failed but on typing only mongod is working)

2.i can not connect to remote mongo server through my robomongo it says **"cannot connect to mongodb"**

my mongo.config file -- >

```
 # mongod.conf

    # for documentation of all options, see:
    #   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
      dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
      journal:
        enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    # how the process runs
    processManagement:
      fork: true  # fork and run in background
    #pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0,10.0.0.1,127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bindIp` setting is a bit weird. Why the comma separated list? Just use `0.0.0.0`.

After that, open port `27017` in your Security Group and you will be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks i did all the things but forgot to add in Security group your answer reminds me

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. If you can connect using the `mongo` shell, then the server is running. Otherwise you'll see an error like `Connection refused` and `exception: connect failed`
2. By default, AWS firewall is very restrictive. Please check if you allow incoming connection to port 27017 from any host. There will be a warning saying you are opening the port to everyone, but it is necessary to allow connections to the database.